# How do I make Java 8 the default on a Mac?

Tags: java

I have installed Java 8 on a Mac (OS 10.9.5) and it now appears in System Preferences. However, when I type the following in the command line:

```
java -version
```

it shows that I am using version 6:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

How can I make version 8 the default?

Comment: Did you install the Java 8 JDK or just the JRE? You need the JDK for the command line `java` tool.

Comment: @IanRoberts No, you don't. You need the JDK period for `javac` and some other development tools, but not for `java`.

Comment: @Brian my comment was poorly phrased - if you have the JRE then you can certainly run `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` directly on the command line, but if you want the `/usr/bin/java` stub to detect Java 8 then you need the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this to the .bash_profiles file. It should be under the /User/yourUsername/ folder. if it is not there please create it.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:$PATH:
```

**note you might have to change the path/version based on your machine**

Step 1: Open terminal and navigate to User/yourUsername/ folder
Step 2: type vi .bash_profile and then hit enter
Step 3: hit 'I' so that it in insert mode (you can verify this by looking and the left bottom corner)
Step 4: type the above two lines whit appropriate path.
Step 5: hit esc key and the press ':wq' without the the ' (Your should see this getting type and bottom left corner) then hit enter

## EDIT :

---

This should set up with what you need.

You can also do this approach :

In Terminal, navigate to the following location:

cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/

The CurrentJDK symlink in this directory was still pointing to an older Java version. To resolve this, remove the symlink and create a new one pointing to the new Java 7 JDK (you may need to use sudo to run these commands):

rm CurrentJDK
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/ CurrentJDK

**note you might have to change the path/version based on your machine**

This is what it should be done to get rid of the error for unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/ 
sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/README 
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/README 
ls -ltr /etc | grep sudoers.d 
sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d
 
sudo chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: Thanks @wrongAnswer - I have tried to create a .bash_profiles file for jdk1.8.0_20 and used your commands but this is still not working... sorry, would you be able to provide basic step-by-step instructions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: on you terminal if you do 'echo $PATH' without the quotes what does it say ?

Comment: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: Your path doesn't even have jdk 8 ... i think your .bash_profile has .txt extension the file name should be only '.bash_profile' nothing else in extension or before of the .

Comment: Please check the edit and delete any previous files that you have created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your very good instructions, however afterwards I again typed `java -version` and it still says 1.6.0_65... Thanks again for your help

Comment: Please check the edit version that should work perfectly !!!

Comment: I get the following error: `rm: CurrentJDK: Permission denied`. Thank a lot for your help, sorry for being annoying...